# Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8, spring-jdbc

I am working on uplifting Java version and deployment tool for an existing legacy Spring MVC project. While deploying them in Tomcat 8.5, facing the below error.

```
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed


       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDetailsDaoImpl' defined in class path resource 
         [com/test/dao/dao-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'searchDetails' while setting bean property 'searchDetails';
         nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchDetails' defined in class path resource 
         [com/test/dao/dao-beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
         Could not instantiate bean class [com.aexp.travel.docdelivery.tcapp.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
         com.test.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall.returningResultSet(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper;)
         Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall;
```

I searched on the error and found it may be due to version mismatch ,so i did `mvn dependency:tree` but no where I am able to get the conflicts.
    Attached is my result:

```
[INFO] |  \- quartz:quartz:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.americanexpress.dtr.legacy:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf:json-lib:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf:ezmorph:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.0:test
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:test
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-util:jar:1.3.4:test
[INFO] |  \- aspectwerkz:aspectwerkz-core:jar:0.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.6.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.0.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.3:compile
```

The method which is throwing error do exist in my project.
Attached is the class.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;


public class DocDeliveryJdbcCall extends SimpleJdbcCall{

    public DocDeliveryJdbcCall(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public DocDeliveryJdbcCall(DataSource dataSource,String storedProcedureName,String clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //create jdbc call object
        super(dataSource);
        //set stored procedure name
        withProcedureName(storedProcedureName);
        //set return type class with pointer(RESULT) to result set.
        returningResultSet(DocDeliveryCommonConstants.RESULT,  (RowMapper)ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Class.forName(clazz)));
        compile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public DocDeliveryJdbcCall(DataSource dataSource,String storedProcedureName,RowMapper rowMapper) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        //create jdbc call object
        super(dataSource);
        //set stored procedure name
        withProcedureName(storedProcedureName);
        //set return type class with pointer(RESULT) to result set.
        **returningResultSet(DocDeliveryCommonConstants.RESULT, rowMapper);**
        compile();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Attached is my dao-beans.xml:

```
<bean id="Storage" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/STORE" /> 
      </bean>

      <bean id="fieldDetailsDaoImpl" class="com.test.daoImpl.FieldDetailsDaoImpl">
            <property name="searchDetails" ref="searchDetails"/>
            <property name="getPassangersDetails" ref="getPassangersDetails"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="searchDetails" class="com.test.DocDeliveryJdbcCall">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="Storage"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="csp_SEARCH_Get"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="reasearchPnrRM"/>
     </bean>

     <bean name="reasearchPnrRM" class="com.test.rowMapper.ResearchPnrRM"/>

     <bean id="getPassangersDetails" class="com.test.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="Storage"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="csp_DOC_DETAILS_Get"/>
            <constructor-arg index="2" ref="passangerRM"/>
     </bean>

     <bean name="passangerRM" class="com.test.rowMapper.PassengerRM"/>
```

Highlighted one is throwing error.

Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: Mark `DocDeliveryJdbcCall` class as component using `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Did @Component ,but still facing the same

Comment: Do you have a class searchDetails in your project? if yes the mark it as @Service

Comment: What about `searchDetails` and `fieldDetailsDaoImpl` ? Are they annotated ?

Comment: Please show us `dao-beans.xml` and implementation of `returningResultSet`

Comment: FieldDetailsDaoImpl is annotated as @Repository

Comment: You are mixing Spring 2.5.6 and 3.1.0 in one applicaiton. Don't as that leads to these kind of errors.

Comment: Are you having two `DocDeliveryJdbcCall` class?`com.aexp.travel.docdelivery.tcapp.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall`, `com.test.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall` are found in stacktrace.

Comment: apologies...i have one i.e.com.test.dao.DocDeliveryJdbcCall

Comment: @samabcde,Can you pls let me know how can get this 2.5.6 jar because in build path it is not available.Hope this is the version mismatch

Comment: Quartz is pulling in 2.5.6 (check your output). Also you are using an old version of Spring (3.1) which might nog support the Java and tomcat version you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanx @M.Deinum,this helped me resolve the error